# In Fire fox browser Backspace was not working when I use allow-pattern in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, firefox

I'm new in the front end. I'm using the allow-pattern directive for validation.In that backspace or arrow keys are not working when I open it on Mozilla firefox browser.Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
<input type="text" name="emergency_contact_name" allow-pattern="[a-z]"  ng-model="name" id="name" class="form-control parsley-success" value="name" data-parsley-id="0951">
```

Comment: Is it [this](https://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/post/angularjs-directive-labs-allowpattern-directive-more-fun-with-keycodes) `allow-pattern` directive?`

Comment: @jensgram, Yes it is.I already tried this example. When I try this example It allows numeric values also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question *does not* clarify as to the `allow-pattern` implementation. The first hit I get on Google is [this post on CodePen](https://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/post/angularjs-directive-labs-allowpattern-directive-more-fun-with-keycodes). Assuming that's what you're using, take a close look at this:

```
if (!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowOnlyPattern, "i"))) {
    return false;
}
```

This means that *all* other keys are rejected *including* backspace (8), delete (46), left-arrow (37), and right-arrow (39).

A simple (albeit not very pretty) fix is:

```
var controlKeyCodes = [8, 46, 37, 39];
if (!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowOnlyPattern, "i")) && controlKeyCodes.indexOf(keyCode) === -1) {
    return false;
}
```